# Does King's attack, the Ultimate Hellfire Burst Wave Motion Cannon exist in the webcomic?

Tags: one-punch-man

It's been a while since I've read the One Punch Man webcomic. It seems to me that the manga  is taken a direction pretty different to the webcomic, and several concepts (such as Platinum Sperm) didnt even exist in the webcomic.

Does King's attack,  the Ultimate Hellfire Burst Wave Motion Cannon exist in the webcomic?

Comment: I am unable to check, but I believe the answer is, “Yes, it exists in the webcomic.” IIRC, Child Emperor draws up a plan similar to the one in the manga for King to unleash his ultimate technique, and King attempts to do so, imagining a powerful release of energy. For obvious reasons, the attack fails and King retreats from the battle.

Comment: In his imagination, yes.